# should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'(Expo React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, config

How can I resolve this issue. I am getting this error after I upgraded my expo application on my phone:

*Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
• should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.*

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I faced the same issue.
So I upgraded the expo-cli using
`npm install -g expo-cli`
My expo-cli version is 4.4.4 and I can't see the error anymore.
Thank you, Sardorek Aminjonov

Answer (score 6):

@Sardorek, ran into the same problem, spent more than an hour, and finally figured it out.

The solution is to add the Expo SDK version in the `app.json` file. My version is 40.0.1. You can see it in `package.json`.

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz"
```

Upgrading to version 40 has removed it from the `app.json` file.

Now, add the major.minor.0 version in the `app.json` file like:

```
"sdkVersion": "40.0.0"
```

*Looks like you cannot include the maintenance version number. If you do, you will get this error.*

```
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0, 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0, 34.0.0, 35.0.0, 36.0.0, 37.0.0, 38.0.0, 39.0.0, 40.0.0, 41.0.0
Couldn't publish because errors were found. (See logs above.) Please fix the errors and try again.
```

Now, run `expo start`, and voila it works! Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I have solved it by just upgrading my expo-cli

Answer (score 2):

I am using 'yarn start' to launch expo. It looked like libragopi's solution fixed my issue, but after doing a hot refresh the warning was back. I found another possible solution, which may be related to the way you're launching expo (as in my case with yarn)

yarn global add expo-cli

from this forum post https://forums.expo.io/t/having-issue-with-app-json-after-upgrading-expo-app-in-android/51194/4

Answer (score 0):

I landed on the same issue on a different context.
I am [releasing my app with `expo-github-action`](https://github.com/expo/expo-github-action).

My problem was during the build `expo publish --clear --release-channel staging`

```
[08:52:02] - Expo SDK: 41.0.0
[08:52:02] - Release channel: staging
[08:52:02] - Workflow: Managed

[08:52:03] Building optimized bundles and generating sourcemaps...
[08:52:03] Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
[08:52:03]  • should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.
```

**Solved with updating `node-version`**

```
// .github/workflows/staging.yml
...
 steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x      <------- update here
      - uses: expo/expo-github-action@v5
        with:
          expo-version: 4.x      <------- update here
          expo-username: ${{ secrets.EXPO_CLI_USERNAME }}
          expo-password: ${{ secrets.EXPO_CLI_PASSWORD }}
          expo-cache: true
```

Answer (score 0):

For Expo SDK42 is not needed to add `"sdkVersion": "42.0.0"`, it's deprecated and will not work.

The solution is to update `expo-cli` to version 4.9.0 - `npm i expo-cli@4.9.0`

NOTE: be careful because with v4.9.1 it still appears :/

Answer (score 0):

Error? its an expo related breakage

solution?  simply go  to your `app.json` file, add an expo property like so

```
{

  "expo":{
     "appKey":"NodeModulesPath",
  },
  
  "name": "NodeModulesPath",
}
```

ps: you can replace the "nodeModulesPath" with your particular property that is throwing the error

Answer (score -2):

I had that problem so I updated the expo go (the app to run the application) and it fixed