# Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/• should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, expo, node-modules

When running my managed workflow project (SDK 42), I get the above error right before the package builds,and I cannot figure out why. Below is my app.json file from this project:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App-Name",
    "slug": "App-Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist":{
  
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions":[
        
      ],

    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111203/should-not-have-additional-property-nodemodulespathexpo-react-native)?

Comment: I have not. I am afraid if I update my version of Expo CLI, it could crash my project, as I am currently running on version 3.23.2

Would I still be able to upload to the app stores with this error?

Comment: Can't really say if Play Store would allow to upload with this error.

Comment: @Rohit The app still does function as it's supposed to tho, it's just a weird warning I get right before it builds

Comment: Yeah you can ignore build time warning if it does effect your app's function.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Would you also be able to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378658/react-native-v-5-navigation-goback-prop-navigates-to-the-wrong-screen) out by chance?