# React Native v.5 navigation.goBack() prop navigates to the wrong screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I have an app with 5 screens: Screens 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Screen 1 is the "Home Screen" (which is also the landing screen after signing in)
Screen 2 is the "Next Screen" (which follows the Home Screen)
Screen 3 is the "Other Screen" (which follows screen 2)
Screen 4 is the "Chat Screen" (where users could chat with one another)
Screen 5 is Profile Screen (which lives in a "Drawer Navigator that is only accessible from the Home Screen)

A user can access the Chat Screen from either Screen 2 or Screen 3, so I assigned a "navigation.goBack()" prop to the button, so the user would always return to either Screen 2, or Screen 3, depending where they are coming from

This feature works fine, unless a user happens to go to the "Profile Screen" before navigating to Screen 2, or Screen 3.

When a user clicks the "goBack" button, they navigate from the chat screen, to the "Profile Screen" even though they were previously in Screen 2 or Screen 3.

When pressing the "Home" icon on the drawer, they end up back in the "Chat Screen" and end up stuck in this loop.

How do I make the navigator understand to return to the previous screen, and not a screen they were at in the drawer navigator?

Here's how it looks drawn out:

(Start) Screen 1 => Screen 2=> Screen 4 =>(goBack) Screen 2 (This is functions normally)

(Start) Screen 1 => Screen 5 => Screen 1 => Screen 2 => Screen 4 =>(goBack) Screen 2 (How it should function)

(Start) Screen 1 => Screen 5=> Screen 1 => Screen 2 => Screen 4 =>(goBack) Screen 5 (What it's doing)

EDIT: Here is some of the code

```
//Code that builds the main tab navigator

const MainTab = createStackNavigator();

function MainTabScreen ({ navigation }){
  return(

<MainTab.Navigator screenOptions ={{
      headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:"#009387" ,        
        },
        gestureEnabled: false,
        headerTintColor: '#fff', 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: height*0.023,
          textAlign: 'center',

        }
    }}>

    <MainTab.Screen name = "Home" component={HomeScreen} options= {{
      title: '',
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button name = "menu" size={25} backgroundColor= "#009387" onPress={ () => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Icon.Button>
          ), 
      }}/>

      <MainTab.Screen name = "NextScreen" component={NextScreen} options= {{
        title: i18n.t(''),
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button name = "arrow-left" size={25} backgroundColor= "#009387" onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}/> 
          ) 
      }}/>

      <MainTab.Screen name = "OtherScreen" component={OtherScreen} options= {{
        title: i18n.t('') ,
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerLeft: null,
      }}/>

      <MainTab.Screen name = "ChatScreen" component={ChatScreen} options= {{
        title: '' ,
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerLeft: ()=>(
        <Icon.Button name = "arrow-left" size={25} backgroundColor= "#009387" onPress={ () => navigation.goBack()}/>          
        )
      }}/>


  </MainTab.Navigator>

  )}
```

Code that creates the Drawer tab

```
export function DrawerContent (props){
    return(
          <Drawer.Section>
          <DrawerItem
              icon={({color, size }) => (
                <Icon 
                  name="home-outline"
                  color={color}
                  size={height*0.032}
            />
            )}
            label= {i18n.t('')}
            onPress={()=>{props.navigation.navigate('HomeDrawer')}}
            />

            <DrawerItem
              icon={({color, size }) => (
              <Icon 
                name="account-outline"
                color={color}
                size={height*0.032}
                />
              )}
            label= {i18n.t('')}
            onPress={()=>{props.navigation.navigate('ProfileStackScreen')}}
            />
        </Drawer.Section>

   
      )
  }
```

Code that combines the two into a "StackApp" that is exported into the App.js file

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    function StackApp2() {

  return (
    
    
      <NavigationContainer theme = { theme }>
      
        
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions = {{
        gestureEnabled: false,
      }}>

        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={MainTabScreen} /> 
        <Drawer.Screen name="ProfileStackScreen" component={ProfileStackScreen} /> 

      </Drawer.Navigator>

      )
    }
    </NavigationContainer>

    export default StackApp2
```

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet or diagrammatic representation of your navigation structure? It becomes difficult to understand like this. Also you can check if this works for your nested navigator.`this.props.navigation.goBack(null) `

Comment: @Rohit That unfortunately did not work, however I edited the original post and added the code you requested.