Error while starting the react-native app
The project was working fine, untill I added some new packages.
Now, when I try to start the app, it give me the following error:
Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/ • should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.
And this is my app.json file:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "ApolloClaim",
    "slug": "ApolloClaim",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.rohitkc7.ApolloClaim"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "a0f4ea26-d1b0-418a-8240-8cf86b2407fd"
      }
    }
  }
}

I don't what's wrong and I am very new to React-native.
I think it is the new update of expo-cli.

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111203/should-not-have-additional-property-nodemodulespathexpo-react-native . It's not mentioned what are package versions, including  expo-cli.

The related question is not helpful.

It's unknown if it's helpful or not because the question doesn't contain relevant details. It shows that this problem can be caused by using incompatible package versions. This may be specific to package versions, which are, again, unknown. Please, update it. The problem requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
